# Measuring page load times [server+client] with third party tools

Tags: load-time

We want to capture the page load times from server to client and not just execution time at server. This measurement is for system wide, meaning it should get the page load times from various locations. Ours is suite of intranet applications and the locations are predefined [like, Mt. Laurel, Omaha, etc.].

I know that Jiffy and Episodes provides that feature, but I want to know whether a third party tool exists. I checked with Gomez, WebMetrics, Pingdom and Keynote, but none of them meets our requirements.

Here is the requirement:

1. The tool should provide a way to instrument our applications or use some technology to measure the page load times.
2. It should not require us to install anything on the client side [though it is intranet and controlled environment, we have hundreds of locations, where we don't want to take pain of installing something manually].

Comment: Does the data need to be collected silently during normal usage, or are users at the remote site going to be instructed to navigate to the "benchmarking" page which runs this sequence of load time tests and reports the results back to the central server?

Comment: Yes - The data needs to be collected silently and users will not even know that it exists. A central server should maintain the results and should provide either as a reporting or at least should be query-able. BTW, this is meant for production systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to select the right product for our requirements and it is called [BrowserHawk](http://www.browserhawk.com/).